# how to accepts the multiple arguments for user input and pass it to parameter and print all the items

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

- a function which accepts the multiple arguments of user shopping list and print all the items which user bought from market but i am passing a list as a argument it showing list not single items:
- (Give solution using arbitrary argument concept )

**Here's some code:**

```
def customer_shopping(*shopping_list):
    print("\n--------- Shopping List --------")    
    for element in shopping_list:
        print("You bought: ",element)

shopping_list = []

while True:
    items = input("\nEnter the item you bought from market \nIf you leave enter'quit': ")
    if items == 'quit':
        break
    shopping_list.append(items)

customer_shopping(shopping_list)
```

Comment: Removing the `*` in function definition should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unpacking operator `*` from your function definition and call:

```
def customer_shopping(shopping_list):
...
customer_shopping(shopping_list)
```

This gives output:

```
Enter the item you bought from market 
If you leave enter'quit': banana


Enter the item you bought from market 
If you leave enter'quit': carrot


Enter the item you bought from market 
If you leave enter'quit': quit

--------- Shopping List --------
You bought: Banana
You bought: Carrot
```

Comment: plzzzzz give me solution using arbitrary argument concept ....

Answer (score 0):

The issue is:

```
def customer_shopping(*shopping_list):
```

if you simply remove the * it will print exactly as you want it!